# How to filter by year and by range of months?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to filter my table by year (let's say the user selects 2022 and 2023) and for those two years I want to see the sum value of a month range (let's say from January to June). Here is an image of what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is the code I have which gives me this output:

[image]

```
 output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
  data <- df_tabla_3
 
  
  if (!is.null(input$man)) {
    if ("All" %in% input$man && length(input$man) == 1) {
      # If only "All" is selected, show all data
      data <- df_tabla_3
    } else if (length(input$man) > 0) {
      # If other options are selected, filter the data
      data <- data[data$Fecha %in% input$man,]
    }
  }
  data
  
}))
```